# Burned Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, power, usb

I have an arduino that I programmed a PWM signal on pin 5. When I power the arduino with 12v or USB5v, pin 5 has the PWM signal. Iam checking it with a oscilloscope. Oddly enough the arduino is not recognisable to a windows PC or MAC, the device never shows up on the usb. The LED on the device seem to give all the right signals. The Green ON LED is on. And the L LED is also on. The program is not using serial so the RX and TX are not on.

When I try another Arduino it works fine.

What could I have broke? I am guessing the ATmega328 is fine?

Comment: Try reflashing the ATMega16u2 that does the usb-to-serial. Try it using the [DFU option](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2). If that fails use another [arduino to reflash using ISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) (using the ISP header right near the chip in question. If that also fails most the atmega16u2 is probably broken the board is beyond economical repair

Comment: Tried that, with no luck. Yeah I am not trying to fix for $$ reason, just trying to understand what went wrong.

Comment: `with no luck`. Could you expand on that. Were you unable to update the firmware, or did it not have any effect.

Comment: I was not able to use DFU option because the UNO is not detected by the pc or mac. I tried the ISP option and burned the bootloader, but it still is not detected by the computers.

Comment: Did the ISP programmer successfully verify the flashed rom?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, if anything else work fine, my (first) guess would be the serial to usb adapter. I damaged one a while ago on a breadboard but also dont know how. But it could also be almost everything else. The pwm sketch, in which language is it written and burned? Does the Atmega have a bootloader on it?

Comment: The sketch was really simple, just doing a analogWrite(5, 100);

Comment: And how have you load it onto the arduino?

Comment: Using the arduino IDE

Comment: have you seen any error message inside the status window? would be nice if you tell a bit more..

Comment: The only error I see is the it can't find the usbmodem because the computer is not seeing the uno

Comment: which port uses the command? have you verified it? you said you have more arduinos right? try to communivate to another one using RX/TX pins.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? My other UNO use usb. And yes it is pin 5 sending the signal

Comment: that wasnt my question, ive meant the port you connect the arduino to your computer. it should be like COM1 on windows or like /dev/ttyACM0 on linux

Comment: Yeah it never shows up on windows or mac.

Comment: It also doesn't show up under device manager? Would it be possible for you to boot a linux distro and try it there? Most distros allow outputting detected USB devices and USB related logs so those might help up.